# Can not copy .bat file from network share

Tags: windows, batch-file, network-shares

This is so bizarre to me.

I have a .bat file sitting on a domain-joined workstation, let's call it **Origin**.  Workstation is running Win10 21H2.

I have another workstation, let's call it **Target**, also running 21H2, from which I would like to copy that .bat file to.  This must be a pull operation in which **Target** pulls the file from **Origin**.  ( **Origin** is not allowed to push the file to **Target** )

It should be noted that I am logged in to Target as a regular non-admin domain user, let's call my account `joe`.  The file on **Origin** can only be accessed by Domain Admins, so let's call that user `joe_admin`.

So I open File Explorer on Target, and type \Origin\c$\the\path, after being prompted to enter credentials (where I provide `joe_admin` credentials) I see the `file.bat` that I am looking for.  Hazzah.

How when I drag the file to a local folder, `C:\temp`, I get a network error.  "There is a problem accessing \\Origin\c$    Make sure you are connected to the network and try again."

Well, that's perplexing.  I can see the files.  The **Domain Admins** group has "Full Control" granted to the directory and the file...

So then I rename the file to `file.txt`.. Immediately the file copies.
So then I try renaming it to `file.cmd`.. Immediate copy.
So then I try renaming it to `file.exe`.. Immediate copy.

So then I try `file copy.bat`.  Error.

Ok, then let's try pushing the file... I create a file on **Target**, `c:\temp\push.bat`, and attempt to copy via drag/drop to `\\Origin\c$\the\path\`.  Failure.  Same error as before.
So then I run the test again with `push.txt`.  Immediate success.  Then again with `push.cmd`.  Immediate success.

One last test... copy `push.cmd` from **Target** to **Origin**, then rename the file on **Origin** (via the same Explorer window on Target that did the copy) to `push.bat`.  Rename success.  But I can not copy the file back to Target.

Maybe it's just my workstation, **Target**?  So try to push/pull `.bat` files from other machines.  Negative.

I also can not copy the `.bat` file from **Origin** to another workstation (not Target).

The long and short is that I can not copy `.bat` files around the network.
What is it about `.bat` files that doesn't allow them to be copied from/to a network share?

#### Update I:

It appears that if the `.bat` file is 7 bytes or less in size, it copies fine.  If it is 8 bytes or greater it does not copy.  It does not appear to matter what the content is - only the size.

#### Update II:

Additional testing has narrowed the culprit down to, most likely, out VPN software.  I'll post an additional update once we hear back from the vendor.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: From Target, map a folder on Origin with NET USE.    NET USE Z: \\name_or_IP_of_Origin\Folder ...  What error do you get?  You may also need to set up a user name and password for Target on Origin and permit Folder for this user name.

Comment: Do you have some kind of antivirus or network protection software that might be treating all bat files as malicious?

Comment: @Mokubai - we do of course run AV software.  It is not flagging the file as malicious.  The file is perfectly fine on the HDD and will run in a cmd window just fine.  It's just the transfer that is blocked.   I'll post this in the q as an update:  more testing has narrowed the culprit down to, most likely, our VPN software.

Comment: Same here. I can copy DLL's of any size, but not EXE, BAT and CMD files. Can't rename, and can't `copy con` a new bat file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Win10 when copying .bat files.

The solution i used when copying a .bat from a network drive, was to copy the .bat to "C:/Documents" and then COPYING that file, doing that i could always copy to wherever i needed to.

It seems to me that Windows tries to protect you from external .bat files that don't come from your OWN computer.

Try that to see if it helps.

Regards,